# SQL: How to bring back 20 columns in a select statement, with a unique on a single column only?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a huge select statement, with multiple inner joins, that brings back 20 columns of info.

Is there some way to filter the result to do a unique (or distinct) based on a single column only?

Another way of thinking about it is that when it does a join, it only grabs the first result of the join on a single ID, then it halts and moved onto joining by the next ID.

I've successfully used `group by` and `distinct`, but these require you to specify many columns, not just one column, which appears to slow the query down by an order of magnitude.

**Update**

The answer by @Martin Smith works perfectly.

When I updated the query to use this technique:

- It more than doubled in speed (1663ms down to 740ms)
- It used less T-SQL code (no need to add lots of parameters to the `GROUP BY` clause).
- It's more maintainable.

**Caveat (very minor)**

Note that you should only use the answer from @Martin Smith if you are absolutely sure that the rows that will be eliminated will always be duplicates, or else this query will be non-deterministic (i.e. it could bring back different results from run to run).

This is *not* an issue with `GROUP BY`, as the TSQL syntax parser will prevent this from ever occurring, i.e. it will only let you bring back results where there is no possibility of duplicates.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If there are 20 different columns you select, say first name, last name, street, etc., you get 20 columns of course. What else? It sounds like you don't know exactly how to use GROUP BY, but that's just guessing. What are you trying to achieve? Please show us some sample data, what you get now and what you want to get instead.

Comment: Is it arbitrary which row is returned or do you want a certain one?

Comment: My query is such that if there are any duplicate rows before the `Distinct By`, they will be the same, so it doesnt matter which one comes back. @Martin Smith has an answer which looks like it will work perfectly.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner. To clarify, I did successfully use `GROUP By`, but it slowed the query down by an order of magnitude. I updated my question to clarify this. The answer by Martin Smith looks perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `row_number` for this

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YourCol ORDER BY YourOtherCol) AS RN,
--Rest of your query here
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. It's more than twice as fast as the equivalent query using `GROUP BY` (1663ms vs. 740ms), uses less SQL code, and is more maintainable. However, there is one very minor caveat, I have edited my original question to note this.